# Store 600 sound files, 5-20kb each, inside core data

Tags: ios, core-data, audio

I know "I should not store large files in core data and it is better to save them in the file system".
But...
I still wish to try this out as my sound files are between 5-20 kb each and to my needs it will be great if they will be in core data. to be a extra careful I will store them in a different entity.

Now!

1. Do i have to use binary data or can I use transformable object? if i can, i will be happy know how?
2. still, why would't you do it even with such small files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a transformer really depends on what object you want to transform the sound data into.

Apple has example code for a [UIImage transformer](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#samplecode/PhotoLocations/Listings/Classes_UIImageToDataTransformer_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008909-Classes_UIImageToDataTransformer_m-DontLinkElementID_14).

Keep in mind that the transformer is called each time the object is fetched, so the overhead should be kept to a minimum.  You probably wouldn't want to instantiate an AVAudioPlayer for each object every time the UITableViewController fetches an object to draw a cell, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data Programming Guide: [Large Data Objects (BLOBs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW5)

> The exact definition of "small", "modest", and "large" is fluid and
>   depends on an application's usage. A loose rule of thumb is that
>   objects in the order of kilobytes in size are of a "modest" sized and
>   those in the order of megabytes in size are "large" sized.

Your sound files are small enough to store it in the same table. Use a separate entity only between 100K and 1 MB. What is the advantage in storing a sound as a transformable? if you can't think of any just use binary data.